# how to use thymeleaf and angular 4 together?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've been trying to mix angular with thymeleaf together, but I couldn't find a way. Can any one help me to clear out this confusion !

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you know some angular4, thymeleaf and as you have tagged spring-boot, assume a spring boot application configured for thymeleaf.

By convention spring-boot will look for static resources (css, javascript, ..) in `src/main/resources/static`.

By convention spring-boot set up for thymeleaf will resolve templates from `src/main/resources/templates`.

There are many options for including angular4 code, what follows is one very simple approach

below is a top level angular project used to build the java script code and a typical spring boot layout showing directories laid out following convention

[image: basic layout]

After you have built your java-script bundles you copy them into the `src/main/resources/static/js` directory.
I am not using the production build bundles as its easier to show whats going on but you would follow the same approach with a production build.
[image: js bundles]

You would make a thmeleaf view to inject into a thymeleaf layout.

```
<head>
    <title>Admin Panel</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="js/favicon.ico?v=2">
</head>
<th:block layout:fragment="content">
    <div class="ang-comp">
    <demo-app >Loading...</demo-app>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/inline.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.bundle.js"</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/styles.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.bundle.js"></script>
</th:block>
```

the imports from the .../static/js directory here `<demo-app>` is the selector for the angular component.

This is the simplest approach, you can use tools, [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) and [gradle-node-plugin](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin)
To develop the angular code with the devsever you would need to set up the [proxy.conf.json](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md)
Code for a simple approach using gradle can be found here [simple code](https://github.com/nsavageJVM/thymeleaf_ng_demo)
note to resolve the thymeleaf views you can use the [SpringBootServletInitializer](https://github.com/nsavageJVM/thymeleaf_ng_demo/blob/master/src/main/java/org/server/ServletInitializer.java)
note to declare thymeleaf settings in [gradle.properties](https://github.com/nsavageJVM/thymeleaf_ng_demo/blob/master/gradle.properties) you would do a similar thing with maven properties.

**notes**
[angular production build](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build)
[thmeleaf fragments](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html)
[thmeleaf dialects](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/sayhelloextendingthymeleaf5minutes.html)
[spring boot conventions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html)

Comment: would you know a basic github example of this ?

Comment: @user1767316
 maybe this would help https://github.com/nsavageJVM/thymeleaf_ng_demo

Comment: thanks @NigelSavage , I should do the same using maven